# Is it possible to define this object using Kripke-Joyal Semantics

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory

I've been looking into Kripke-Joyal semantics and, for each formula $\phi(x)$ defining an object $\{ x \, | \, \phi(x) \}$. Is it possible to, somehow, "fix a variable"? Let's say I've got a formula $\phi(x,y)$. Would I be able to "fix" $y$ and construct $\{ x \, | \, \phi(x,y) \}$. I'm trying to generalize what would in topos $\mathbf{Set}$ be a function $f:Y \to \mathcal{P}X$ such that $f(y) = \{ x \in X \, | \, \phi(x,y) \}$. The left hand side would, of course, be $f \circ y$. But which morphism would be on the right hand side. Since $x$ is the only free varible, i assume it would be a subobject of $X$ (where $x:U \to X$ is the generalized element).

I was thinking about somehow using the projection from $\{ (x,y) \, | \, \phi(x,y) \}$, but never got anywhere.

Another idea was just defining a term $\sigma(y) := \forall y(f(y) = \{ x \, | \, \phi(x,y) \})$ but didn't know how would I do it, since the very thing I'm trying to define is inside that term.

The next idea was using the exponential transpose, but then I would end up with a term of type $\Omega^Y$, instead of $\Omega$, so I couldn't get the pullback of $1 \to \Omega$ along $\lambda y \phi(x)$.

Comment: If you have a global element $y : 1 \to Y$, then you can indeed fix it to form this subobject.

Comment: A subobject of $X\times Y$ is the same as an arrow $X\times Y\to \Omega$, which is the same as an arrow $Y\to \Omega^X = \mathcal{P}(X)$. But I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I'm asking if there is a way to look at a formula with 2 free variables, $\phi(x,y)$, take some $y:U \to Y$ and look for all $x:V \to X$ such that $\phi(x,y)$ holds, for that fixed $y$, in order to construct a subobject of $\{ x \, | \, \phi(x,y) \} \hookrightarrow X$.

Comment: Yes, you can take a formula $\phi (x, y)$ and form a function $Y \to P X$ as you wish. It's actually easy: such a formula defines a function $X \times Y \to \Omega$, so by transposition you get $Y \to \Omega^X$, as desired.

Comment: A related question which this brought up for me: is it possible to define a "dependent type" $\lambda (y : Y) . \{ x \mid \phi(x, y) \}$, i.e. an object of the topos with a morphism to $Y$?  (I guess this is easy: $\phi : X \times Y \to \Omega$ corresponds to a subobject of $Y$, and that subobject along with $\pi_2 \circ inc$ seems like it should be the required object.)